# How batch_size parameter works on Keras .fit() when using custom generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Given that my dataset is too big to load in memory all at once I opted to use a custom generator with a batch size of 32, this means my data will be loaded in batch sizes of 32. Now if I understand correctly when I feed this generator as a paramenter to the `.fit()` of Keras that means that in one epoch all of the training data will be seen by the model in batches of 32. So my question is, if I specify a batch_size to the .`fit()` method so I can control when the weights are updated, how would this work, or should I not specify it and the weights will be updated for every batch of the generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would leave it as it is. As the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#fit) explain, when you define the batch size in `model.fit(...)`, you are defining the:

> [...] Number of samples per gradient update. [...]

However if you read on, it also says:

> Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets,
> generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate
> batches).

So, the batch size from your generator should be respected when passing it to `model.fit`